# Base 64 encoding issue

Tags: c#, .net, base64

I have some Base64 encoded data as a byte array that I'm trying to convert back to it's original format.

The data is reaches my function encoded twice over. What I want to achieve is something like:

```
string encoded = "some base 64 string";
byte [] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoded));
```

The statement above is wrong of course as I could not figure out which combination of functions to use and ran into unicode issues when I tried. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hex is not base64 - what does your data look like?

Comment: A little confused on what the data looks like. is it hex? "a05f" that describes a string encoded with base64? or is it a normal string with base64 encoding (like giberish because of the ascii conversion).

Comment: You're right. It is Base64 ending with a = sign at the end.

Comment: Changed the title from Hex to Base64 and added some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you're trying to do this:

- Convert a base64 string into a byte array
- Convert the byte array to an ASCII string
- Convert that string to a byte array with base64

In that case, your statement would look something like this:

```
byte[] twiceDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encoded)));
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it matter what the source bytes were? For example bytes from a word document rather than plain text.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Nope. base64 is base64, and can encode any binary data.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, the problem was a mismatch between Unicode and ASCII while encoding and decoding respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample data and code below, I could get the signature of the `docx` (also `zip`) file (*`50 4B 03 04 14 00`*). If the sample you posted is from the start of your `encoded` string, most probably, below code will work.

```
byte[] buf = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
var hex2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf);
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(hex2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I depends what output format you prefer. 
This is a small sample code which decrypts your base64 value and returns a string in UTF8 format:

```
public static string DecodeFrom64(string value)
{
    byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a `byte[]` that contains base64 encoded data, and you want to get a `string` that contains the original string.

The first thing you have to do is get that `byte[]` into a `string`. Assuming you know how many bytes are in the array, and you know what text encoding was used (i.e. UTF-8, Unicode, ASCII, etc.), you can write:

```
string base64String = Utf8Encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Substitute the correct text encoding for the `Utf8Encoding` there. If the string really is base64, then Utf8Encoding should work. Or perhaps one of the Unicode encodings, if it's 2 bytes per character.

You should then be able to get the original string like this:

```
string originalString = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

Comment: Would it matter what the source bytes were? For example bytes from a word document rather than plain text.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: It might matter. It's tough to say without knowing how those bytes got into your program. If you're reading from a Word document, I suppose it's possible that there could be formatting instructions and such interspersed with the actual data bytes. I don't know enough about the Word document data format to say.